# Exception while converting XMLGregorianCalendar date 2022-11-24T13:35:00 into ISO_8601

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have an XMLGregorianCalendar date in the below format:

`2022-11-23T13:53:31`

I want to convert it to ISO_8601 format like below:

`2022-11-23T13:53:31.890Z`

So I am getting below exception:

`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-11-23T13:53:31' could not be parsed at index 19`

I have tried the below code:

```
public static boolean checkIfDateMatches( String fromDate, String toDate, String inputDate ) throws Exception {
    boolean flag = false;
    Date start = Date.from(Instant.parse(fromDate));
    Date end = Date.from(Instant.parse(toDate));
    Date input = Date.from(Instant.parse(inputDate));
    if( input.compareTo(start) >= 0 && input.compareTo(end) <= 0 ) {
        flag = true;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you

Comment: There is a typo, I gues "35" vs "53" minutes. Also, your desired result yield _more_ information than your input. That won't fly. Then, your input does not _have_ an index 19, so you may need to review your parsing template.

Comment: When you can use the modern `Instant`, class, then why on Earth use the outdated and poorly designed `Date`? Your `XMLGregorianCalendar` already prints in ISO 8601 format. Are you sure that it is in UTC? By appending `Z` you are claiming that it is.

Comment: @Fildor the issue is not type, I have updated to be same.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes I am sure it is ISO_8601 format. In the whole response I am getting all dates ending with `Z` but this only is coming without `Z`. if I append `Z` at the last. Should it be considered good thing ?

Comment: @OleV.V. or else is there any way that i can convert this date to java date and from their make a conversion to iso_8601 so the the new date comes with `Z` ?

Comment: You have a datetime as `String` without an offset or a zone, which has a length of 19. It cannot be parsed at index 19, which it does not have. The conclusion is the parser expects more than this `String` can offer, in particular, an offset or a zone. Do you want to declare this datetime UTC?

Comment: *if I append Z at the last. Should it be considered good thing ?* It’s a dangerous thing to do if you are not 100 % sure the time is in UTC. I am thinking it is more likely in the local time zone of the sender (or your local time zone if the sender knows which one that is), in which case you need to convert to UTC first.

Comment: A detail, where are you expecting the `.890` (fraction of second) to come from? They are not in your input. Fortunately [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) does not require any fraction, so you can likely leave it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to convert the example input to UTC, you will need to make sure it actually is UTC. Otherwise you would just *append* a `Z` and declare it UTC.

The `DateTimeParseException` tells you there's information missing in the `String` because a non existent index is attempted to be parsed. The input has a length of 19, so its last index is 18.

That means, in this case, the `String` cannot be (reliably) assigned to a zone or offset. Zone and offset are unkown. They have been expected at/from index 19.

If you can verify the input is a UTC time, you can use the following example that makes the input a comparable UTC datetime: An `OffsetDateTime`…

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input WITHOUT OFFSET
    String input = "2022-11-23T13:53:31";
    // parse it AND DECLARE IT UTC
    OffsetDateTime odt = LocalDateTime.parse(input)
                                      .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    // print the result
    String msg = String.format("IN:  %s\nOUT: %s", 
                               input, 
                               odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME));
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Output:

```
IN:  2022-11-23T13:53:31
OUT: 2022-11-23T13:53:31Z
```

You can compare `OffsetDateTime`s, just have a look at the docs.
If you need the milliseconds / fractions of second, define a custom `DateTimeFormatter`.

Remember to make sure the input **is UTC**.